# Odoo Report CSS not rendered properly

Tags: css, xml, odoo, odoo-13

Hello i am trying to style a report in odoo but the report is not rendered correctly.
Like in the picture some rows get cut of, others go in the next line. Moreover if i replace the span with the content with fields of the model the hole text shrinks.
If i take the same css outside of odoo everything is styled like i want.

What am i missing?

```
<odoo>
<data>
    <template id="test_id">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="doc">
            <t t-call="web.basic_layout">
                <div class="page">
                    <div class="row border-bottom border-secondary">
                        <div class="col">
                            <h1 style="color: #013686;">Test</h1>
                            <h2>test</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row text-muted">
                        <div class="col">
                            <h3 class="text-dark">Test 1</h3>
                            <div class="row mb-2">
                                <span class="col-4 text-wrap">Something Test 1:</span>
                                <span class="col">test test testsgddfgdfhbgfthft test test test test test</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row mb-2">
                                <span class="col-4 text-wrap">Something Test 2:</span>
                                <span class="col">test test test test testdfgdfgbdfgbdfgb test test test</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row mb-2">
                                <span class="col-4 text-wrap">Something Test 3:</span>
                                <span class="col">testgkhgkgjfjtfs ersesefgsdegdrhg dfhfdhrfjfgjgf testdgfsgddghdfh dhdhfdfgdgdrgdfjgk test test test testdfgbdrfgb drgdgwsefgs test test</span>
                            </div>
                            <h3 class="text-dark">Test 2</h3>
                            <div class="row mb-2">
                                <span class="col-4 text-wrap">Something Test 4:</span>
                                <span class="col">test test test test test test test test</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row mb-2">
                                <span class="col-4 text-wrap">Something Test 5:</span>
                                <span class="col">test test test test test test test test</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row mb-2">
                                <span class="col-4 text-wrap">Something Test 6:</span>
                                <span class="col">test test test testsfdsfvcsdfvsdef test test test test</span>
                            </div>
                            <h3 class="text-dark">Test 3</h3>
                            <div class="row mb-2">
                                <span class="col-4 text-wrap">Something Test 7:</span>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="mb-2">
                                        <span>test1 test1 test1 test1sfvsedgbdrthtfdrgdsfgs test1 test1 test1 test1</span>
                                        <span>test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mb-2">
                                        <span>test1 test1 test1sefseghdrgrhgdrhdrhgd test1 test1 test1 test1 test1</span>
                                        <span>test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mb-2">
                                        <span>test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1sefsegdsfrggs test1</span>
                                        <span>test2 test2 test2sefvsgdrgdg test2 test2 test2 test2 test2</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <h3 class="text-dark">Test 4</h3>
                            <div class="row mb-2">
                                <span class="col-4 text-wrap">Something Test 8:</span>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="mb-2">
                                        <span>test1 test1 test1 test1sfvsedgbdrthtfdrgdsfgs test1 test1 test1 test1</span>
                                        <span>test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mb-2">
                                        <span>test1 test1 test1sefseghdrgrhgdrhdrhgd test1 test1 test1 test1 test1</span>
                                        <span>test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mb-2">
                                        <span>test1gbdsvbdfhbftgjgzjgjgzhj test1rhgdrgdgbdrgbdrgbd test1 test1sfvdsgdsgdrfhgbdftrhbd dfgdfghbfdhbgf test1 test1 test1sefsegdsfrggs test1</span>
                                        <span>test2 test2 test2sefvsgdrgdg test2 test2 test2 test2 test2</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <h3 class="text-dark">Test 5</h3>
                            <div class="row mb-2">
                                <span class="col-4 text-wrap">Something Test 9:</span>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="mb-2">
                                        <span>test1 test1 test1 test1sfvsedgbdrthtfdrgdsfgs test1 test1 test1 test1</span>
                                        <span>test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mb-2">
                                        <span>test1 test1 test1sefseghdrgrhgdrhdrhgd test1 test1 test1 test1 test1</span>
                                        <span>test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mb-2">
                                        <span>test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1sefsegdsfrggs test1</span>
                                        <span>test2 test2 test2sefvsgdrgdg test2 test2 test2 test2 test2</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </t>
        </t>
    </template>
</data>
</odoo>
```

[Picture of Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3dVO.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to change "web.basic_layout" to "report.html_container".

```
<template id="test_id">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="doc">
            <t t-call="report.html_container">...
```

[image]

Comment: With report.html_container i get the error external id not found.